# How do I make a filter for ListView?

Tags: android, listview, filter

I am developing an application, and I want to filter items in `ListView`, but items Ids are defined as Strings from another class(constructors) and filter doesn't work. (nothing happens)

I want filter to search through these Strings from that constructors, yet I do not know how to.

Here's my `mainActivity` Class:

```
    package com.example.industrialcraft;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.R;

public class Items extends Activity {

    private List<Items_id> myItems = new ArrayList<Items_id>();
    ArrayAdapter<Items_id> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.items_industrialcraft);


        populateItems();
        adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_industrialcraft);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);



        registerClickCallback();





    }





    private void populateItems() {

        myItems.add(new Items_id("Bronze Helmet", "Bronze_Helmet"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Bronze Chestplate", "Bronze_Chestplate"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Bronze Leggings", "Bronze_Leggings"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Bronze Boots", "Bronze_Boots"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Nano-Helmet", "Nano_Helmet"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Nano-Bodyarmor", "Nano_Bodyarmor"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Nano-Leggings", "Nano_Leggings"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Nano-Boots", "Nano_Boots"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("QuantumSuit Helmet", "Quantumsuit_Helmet"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("QuantumSuit Bodyarmor", "Quantumsuit_Bodyarmor"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("QuantumSuit Leggings", "Quantumsuit_Leggings"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("QuantumSuit Boots", "Quantumsuit_Boots"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Scuba Helmet", "Scuba_Helmet"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Hazmat Suit", "Hazmat_Suit"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Hazmat Suit Leggings", "Hazmat_Suit_Leggings"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Rubber Boots", "Rubber_Boots"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("BatPack", "Batpack"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("CF Backpack", "CF_Backpack"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Composite Vest", "Composite_Vest"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Electric Jetpack", "Electric_Jetpack"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Jetpack", "Jetpack"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Lappack", "Lappack"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Nightvision Goggles", "Nightvision_Goggles"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Solar Helmet", "Solar_Helmet"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Static Boots", "Statatic_Boots"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Booze Barrel", "Booze_Barrel"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Crop-Matron", "Crop_Matron"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Crop", "Crop"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Coffee Beans", "Coffee_Beans"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Coffee Powder", "Coffee_Powder"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Grin Powder", "Grin_Powder"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Hydration Cell", "Hydration_Cell"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Hops", "Hops"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Stone Mug", "Stone_Mug"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Coffee", "Coffee"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Dark Coffee", "Dark_Coffee"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Cropnalyzer", "Cropnalyzer"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Electric Hoe", "Electric_Hoe"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Fertilizer", "FErtilizer"));
        myItems.add(new Items_id("Weed-EX", "Weed_EX"));



    }


    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Items_id>{

        public MyListAdapter(){
            super(Items.this, R.layout.items_industrialcraft_buttons, myItems);
        }

        EditText search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = convertView;
            if(itemView == null){
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.items_industrialcraft_buttons, parent, false);
            }

            // Find item to work with

            Items_id currentItem = myItems.get(position);

            search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { 
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence currentItem, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // When user changed the

                    Items.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(currentItem);   
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
                }
            });

            //Fill the view 
            TextView makeText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textId);
            makeText.setText(currentItem.getId());
            return itemView;
        }



    }

    private void registerClickCallback() {
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_industrialcraft);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position,
                    long id) {
                Items_id clicked = myItems.get(position);

                //Find item
                Items_id currentItem = myItems.get(position);

                String abc = currentItem.getActivity();

                String activitys = abc; 

                try{
                    Class classes = Class.forName("com.example.industrialcraft." + activitys);
                    Intent i = new Intent(Items.this, classes);
                    startActivity(i);
                }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }

        });
    }







}
```

Here is my `Items_id` Class:

```
package com.example.industrialcraft;

public class Items_id {

    private String id;
    private String activity;

    public Items_id(String id, String activity){
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getActivity() {
        return activity;
    }
}
```

Comment: > Please see this link.. [Here is good example](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/)

Answer (score 0):

> Please remove

```
EditText search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { 
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence currentItem, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // When user changed the

                    Items.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(currentItem);   
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
                }
            });
```

> from MyListAdapter and put it in oncreate method, and in filter use
>   your condition whatever you wants.It not solved yet then let me know.

Comment: Will try and I let you know later this day and I don't exactly know how to set condition for filter.

Comment: It still doesnt work. I dont know how to set condition for filter, so I ask you to please explain me or give me some tutorial or link me something that will explain filter or give me a hint. Anyway, Thanks for help!!!

Comment: I already provide you a link (http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/), in it everything is well defined and implemented. read it carefully and implement it . if not able to implement, then let me know.

Comment: I made filter and impliment thinks from that link you gave me, but when I try to filter, nothing changes and i dont know why. Code is in anwser.

Comment: I think the problem is within the filter method, more specific somewhere in else statment, but I dont know what it is..

Comment: have you done all work, which i  told you.please post your updated MyListAdapter code here. then i will provide you solution.

Comment: add line arrayList = myItems; in MyListAdapter constractor and also override getsize() method of MyListAdapter add(int getSize() {return arrayList .size();}).

Comment: Look I figured it out and is working now. But your source is wrong, at the filter function tere must be NO else statment after if statment!!!Or you can just not write .clear() function in else statment!!!! But anyhow, thanks for help and that source you gave me was really usefull!!! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

Items class:

```
    package com.example.industrialcraft;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.R;

public class Items extends Activity {

    private List<Items_id> myItems = new ArrayList<Items_id>();
    private List<Items_id> arrayList = new ArrayList<Items_id>();
    ArrayAdapter<Items_id> adapter;
    String activity[];
    String id[];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.items_industrialcraft);


        populateItems();
        adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_industrialcraft);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        final MyListAdapter fil = new MyListAdapter();
        String abcd = "";
        fil.filter(abcd);
        final EditText search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { 
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence a, int position, int arg2, int arg3) {
                String text = search.getText().toString();
                fil.filter(text);  


            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

            }
        });

        registerClickCallback();





    }





    private void populateItems() {

        activity = new String[] {"Bronze_Helmet", "Bronze_Chestplate", "Bronze_Leggings"};

        id = new String[] {"Bronze Helmet", "Bronze Chestplate", "Bronze Leggings"};


        for (int i = 0; i < activity.length; i++) 
        {
            Items_id wp = new Items_id(id[i], activity[i]);
            myItems.add(wp);
        }




    }




    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Items_id>{

        public MyListAdapter(){
            super(Items.this, R.layout.items_industrialcraft_buttons, myItems);
        }



        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = convertView;
            if(itemView == null){
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.items_industrialcraft_buttons, parent, false);
            }

            // Find item to work with

            Items_id currentItem = arrayList.get(position);



            //Fill the view 
            TextView makeText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textId);
            makeText.setText(currentItem.getId());
            return itemView;
        }



        public void filter(String charText){
            arrayList.clear();
            if (charText.length() == 0) {
                arrayList.addAll(myItems);
            } 
            else
            {
                for (Items_id id : arrayList) 
                {
                    if (id.getId().contains(charText)) 
                    {
                        arrayList.add(id);
                    }
                }
            }notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


    }




    private void registerClickCallback() {
        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_industrialcraft);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position,
                    long id) {
                Items_id clicked = arrayList.get(position);

                //Find item
                Items_id currentItem = arrayList.get(position);

                String abc = currentItem.getActivity();

                String activitys = abc; 

                try{
                    Class classes = Class.forName("com.example.industrialcraft." + activitys);
                    Intent i = new Intent(Items.this, classes);
                    startActivity(i);
                }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }

        });
    }







}
```

Items_id class:

```
    package com.example.industrialcraft;

public class Items_id {

    private String id;
    private String activity;

    public Items_id(String id, String activity){
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getActivity() {
        return activity;
    }
}
```